# \def issue (with NumericPlots?)

Tags: macros, pstricks

So I've decided to clean my code for the many plots.

I've basically taken out all the plot data into separate files using

```
\def\plotname{
x1    y1
}
```

Then I use `\input{data.txt}` to load all the plotting data at once and then

```
\begin{NumericDataPlot}{\textwidth}{6cm}
\newpsstyle{MyLineB}{linecolor=blue, linestyle=none,showpoints=true,dotsize=1pt}
\listplot[style=MyLineB]{\plotname}
\end{NumericDataPlot}
```

So far, so good.  Most plots work as expected.  However it turns out there is some issue with some `\def` names.

For instance, using `\muIPS` leads to the following error

```
! Use of \muIPS doesn't match its definition.\addto@pscode ...ef \pst@code {\pst@code #1\space} \listplot[style=MyLineB]{\muIPS}
```

But when I change the name to `\muips` it compiles just fine.

So to sum up, LaTeX seems to be very idiosyncratic about the def name it allows.  Please note that the names were working fine before I used nested input files...

EDITED FOR EXPLANATION :

One of the other names was `\def\muIPS-U` and it wasn't used.

So when I changed to `\muips`, it had no confusion about the definition to use.  Turns out, you can't use - character in the `defname`?  What other characters are forbidden?

Comment: Without a complete example it's difficult to say something. What's the definition of `\muIPS`?

Comment: Like I said it's very hard to make a small working example but it always works until I nest the calls of some 15 files.

\def\muIPS {
1    -110
2    -109.25
3    ....
...
~15000      -0.0002
}

So some 15k coordinates.  This is not about downsampling the plot because it can actually display it when I change the name

How can I attach zip file?

Comment: This will break the Latex...

\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{NumericPlots}

\begin{document}



% WORKS
\frame{
\frametitle{TEST}
\input{plot-gamma}
}


%% COPY DEF CONTENT TO DATA FILE
%% AND \begin{NUMERICPLOT} TO OTHER FILE
%% --> ERROR DEF
\input{Data.txt}
\frame{
\frametitle{TEST}
\input{plot-mu-ind}
}


\end{document}

Comment: Please, supplement the question with the code.

Comment: `\def\muIPS-U` is not possible in this way. Use only characters or `\csname muIPS-U\endcsname`.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your edited question you can use any character in a csname so

```
\csname MUIPS-U\endcsname
```

is OK and constructs the token with name `MUIPS-U` however when parsing the input stream after the escape character (usually `\`) TeX only accepts multiple character sequences if all the characters are of catcode 11 (letter) so by default a-z and A-Z.

If you go

```
\def\muIPS-U{a}
```

That is legal but defines `\muIPS` such that it must be followed by `-U` and then expands to `a`. If it isn't followed be `-U` you get the error:

```
! Use of \muIPS doesn't match its definition.
```

However you can use

```
\@namedef{muIPS-U}{a}
```

which defines the token with name `muIPS-U` to expand to `a`. You can access that token via

```
\@nameuse{muIPS-U}
```

`\@namedef` and `\@nameuse` are LaTeX utilities but you often see the equivalent primitive syntax versions:

```
\expandafter\def\csname muIPS-U\endcsname
```

and

```
\csname muIPS-U\endcsname
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement David Carlisle's answer with a comment based on a guess: most likely, your code contained the definitions in the following order:

```
\def\muIPS{...}
\def\muIPS-U{...}
```

Since TeX interprets the `-U` as "delimiting text" that is not part of the macro name, the second `\def` actually redefines `\muIPS` to be a delimited macro.  Then, later, when you use `\muIPS` in your document, TeX looks unsuccessfully for the required `-U` and gives you that error.

When you switch to using `\muips` for the first one, it is no longer redefined and so you no longer get the error.  There is still a definition of `\muIPS` floating around, still requiring `-U` after it, but with `\muIPS` no longer in use there is no conflict, and using `\muIPIS-U` works by accident, since it has the required form even though TeX interprets the name differently than you do.